# Pass arguments from npm script to bash shell script

Tags: bash, npm

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "bash test.sh"
},
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -l=*|--lib=*)
    LIBPATH="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    --default)
    DEFAULT=YES
    shift # past argument with no value
    ;;
    *)
            # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done
echo "LIBRARY PATH    = ${LIBPATH}"
```

Tried invoking: `npm run test -l=/usr/lib`, ain't working though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derp. Missed the two `--`.

```
npm run install -- -l=/usr/lib
```